# Knockout.js two-way binding for checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js, binding

I'm new to knockout.js and I have some trouble with two-way binding of a checkbox.

I have a table that's bound to a list of "companies".

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: companies">
        <tr>                
            <td>...</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:isCompanyForCommunication, click:$root.checkedNewCompanyForCommunication" /></td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But there should only be 1 company with `isCompanyForCommunication = true` in the table. So when another checkbox is checked, I have to set all other companies to `isCompanyForCommunication = false`. Therefore I created a method in the viewModel to uncheck all other companies.

```
    // Definition of Company
    var Company = function (crmAccountObject, contactId, companyForCommunicationId) {

        this.isCompanyForCommunication = ko.observable(false);
    }

    // Definition of the ViewModel
    var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        // ...

        // Lists
        this.companies = null; // This observableArray is set somewhere else

        // Events
        this.checkedNewCompanyForCommunication = function (company, event) {

            // Set all companies to False
            for (var i = 0; i < self.companies().length; i++) {
                self.companies()[i].isCompanyForCommunication = ko.observable(false);
            }

            // Set the "checked" company to TRUE
            company.isCompanyForCommunication = ko.observable(true);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

However, the changes are not reflected in the HTML page. All other checkboxes remain checked.

I created a simplyfied example in jsfiddle to show what exactly I want to achieve with the checkbox https://jsfiddle.net/htZfX/59/

Someone has any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the value of the `isCompanyForCommunication` but overriding it with a new observable.

Observables are functions and to update them you need to call them with the new value as the argument:

```
this.checkedNewCompanyForCommunication = function (company, event) {

            // Set all companies to False
            for (var i = 0; i < self.companies().length; i++) {
                self.companies()[i].isCompanyForCommunication(false);
            }

            // Set the "checked" company to TRUE
            company.isCompanyForCommunication(true);
            return true;
        }
```

I've also updated your sample code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ed39w3c/).